# What is the equivalent for IIdentityMessageService on ASP.NET Identity 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

On ASP.NET Identity 2.X we could configure a notification infrastructure trhough the `IIdentityMessageService` interface available at the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` library, which was not upgraded to version 3.0.

What are the practices for configuring messaging infrastructure on ASP.NET Identity 3.0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that there is no more email service plugged to the Asp.Net Identity. You just define your own interface. The role of ASP.NET identity is to generate and validate the e-mail confirmation token and the password reset token.

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    Task SendAsync(string to, string subject, string body);
}
```

### To send an e-mail to verify account

```
private async Task SendEmailConfirmation(User user)
{
    string token = await this._userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    string callbackUrl = this._urlHelper.Action("EmailConfirmed", "Account", new ConfirmTokenViewModel(user.Id, token), protocol: this._contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

    await this._emailService.SendAsync(to: user.Email,
            subject: "Confirm your account",
            body: "Please confirm your e-mail by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
}
```

OBS: this._urlHelper is an IUrlHelper. It could be the property Controller.Url or a new instance generated by constructor injection.

Then, to confirm the e-mail

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> EmailConfirmed(ConfirmTokenViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
return View("Error");

    bool succeeded = await this._accountsManager.ConfirmEmail(model.UserId, model.Token);
    return succeeded ? View() : View("Error");
}

public async Task<bool> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
{
    User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user != null)
    {
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
return result.Succeeded;
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Forgot password

```
public async Task GeneratePasswordTokenAndSendEmailAsync(string email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
    if (user != null && await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
    {
string token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
string callbackUrl = this._urlHelper.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new ConfirmTokenViewModel(user.Id, token), protocol: this._contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

await this._emailService.SendAsync(
    to: user.Email,
    subject: "Reset password",
    body: "Reset your password by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>"
});
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
IdentityResult result = await this._accountsManager.ResetPasswordAsync(model);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ResetPasswordConfirmation), "Account");
}
else
    ModelState.AddModelErrors(result.Errors);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

public async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    IdentityResult result = IdentityResult.Success;

    if (model != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.UserId))
    {
User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);
if (user != null)
    result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, model.Token, model.Password);
    }

    return result;
}
```