# ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET CORE 2.2 migration: How to send messages (SMS, email, etc.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**MVC Assembly:** `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`

**CORE Assembly:** `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`

I am migrating from MVC to .NET CORE 2.2. I have created a `MyManager` class that inherits from `UserManager`. The `UserManager` class in MVC has the following properties:

`public IIdentityMessageService EmailService { get; set; }`

`public IIdentityMessageService SmsService { get; set; }`

In .NET CORE 2.2., the `UserManager` does not have these properties. I am guessing that the MVC `UserManager` uses those properties to automatically send messages. It looks like it uses the `EmailService` to automatically send the message that verifies the email address. However, this behavior does not appear to happen in .NET CORE. So, it looks like the `UserManager` no longer handles this.

The question is this: How do you verify a user's email address?

Is this being handled in a different Microsoft assembly or has Microsoft gotten out of that business and farmed it off to a 3rd-party assembly? Or, is there something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent for IIdentityMessageService on ASP.NET Identity 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540273/what-is-the-equivalent-for-iidentitymessageservice-on-asp-net-identity-3-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how i send email verification using [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) in asp.net core.

**step 1 :** Create a class called EmailSender that implements IEmailSender Interface(need to include **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;** for IEmailSender) :

```
 public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        var apiKey = "send grid api key";
        //it looks like this  :
        // var apiKey = "SG.2MpCzyTvIQ.WhHMg6-VBjuqbn9k-8P9m6X9cHM73fk2fzAT5sA4zKc"; 

        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress($"noreply@domaimName.com", "Email title");
        var to = new EmailAddress(email, email);
        var plainTextContent = htmlMessage;
        var htmlContent = htmlMessage;
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        try
        {
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        //return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Step 2 :**  You need to add it as a service using **Dependency Injection** inside the Startup.cs file

```
 services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

**Step 3 :** Inject it into the constructor of the class you want to use it in.

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
      private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
                           {
                                UserName = Input.Email,
                                Email = Input.Email,
                                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
                            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                returnUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Home");
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,"ROleName");
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

> ```
>                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
>                     $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
> ```

```
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

and this should send your email. it works for me and it should for you too.